home made roof trusses
For a garden shed under 200 sq ft (small enough not to require inspection) I would like to know if the following site-made roof truss design using 2x6 dimensional lumber and a combination of nailed plywood gussets and nailed metal tie-plates (not gang-nailed truss plates) would be sturdy enough.
The proposed gussets would be made of 11/32 BCX plywood attached on both faces of the truss and the small rectangles are HTP37Z  3"x7" 16-gauge galvanized tie plates fastened with 0.148 diameter 1.5 inch nails. The tie plates are on one face only. The bottom chord of each truss would be attached to the double top-plate with two hurricane ties, one on each opposite wall, and the trusses would be set at 20" o.c.


your local building codes will specify how roof trusses should be made, these things aren't engineered, they are specified by code.

Below 200 sq ft isn't covered by the local residential code.

And local codes only say "in accordance with standard engineering practice" or something like that.

Some places its 150 sqft or even no side exceeds 12' or something else entirely. Different places have different weather. Start by looking up things like snow load. Consider all the loads including material loads and how they will flow into the ground.  For example, if you tried putting a 500'x500' roof on a structure of only a contiguous 200 sqft interior, what problem would you have?

I worked out a rough estimate, and for a span of 15', a roof $\ (D+L) \ $ load of $ \ 32lbs/ft^2$, and a roof pitch of 4/12, you have approx. $1200-1300$ pounds of tension on the tie rafter. The gussets are soft relative to tension, they will rotate a little.
I would replace the HTP37Z's with ST 23-5/16 in. 16-Gauge Galvanized Strap Ties and use recommended Simpson nails to install them horizontally on each side.

Thank you for the advice regarding the ST23 and the rough estimate.  A follow-up question, please.  Would the following changes help to counteract the rotation?   Replace 11/32 BCX with 11/16 OSB for the gussets;  increase roof pitch from 4:12 to 5:12;  make the building narrower but longer, an 8' span?

yes, all of them will help! and the tension will fall around 900 lbs.
